# page not displaying correctly on Ipad bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following HTML

```
 <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box" id="panel1" style="height:280px">
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0" >
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/black_cherries.png" data-id="1" alt="black_cherries.png" data-name="blackcherry" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/coconut.png" data-id="2" alt="coconut.png" data-name="coconut" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/mango.png" data-id="3" alt="mango.png" data-name="mango" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/strawberries.png" data-id="4" alt="strawberries.png" data-name="strawberries" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/plus.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box" id="panel2" style="height:280px">
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/chocolate.png" data-id="1" alt="chocolate.png" data-name="chocolate" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/cinnamon.png" data-id="2" alt="cinnamon.png" data-name="cinnamon" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
                <div class="row col-xs-12 margin0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/honey.png" data-id="3" alt="honey.png" data-name="honey" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                            <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/vanilla.png" data-id="4" alt="vanilla.png" data-name="vanilla" />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="marginBottom10 visible-xs-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1">
        <img src="/Content/Images/Lab/equals.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="boxTop"></div>
        <div class="box" style="height:280px">
            <p style="font-family: Foco-Regular; display: none; text-transform: uppercase;" id="combinationHeader" class="text-center"></p>
            <img src="" width="260" height="222" alt="" id="combinationImage" class="displaynone">
        </div>
        <div class="boxBtm"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which when displayed in the web browser looks like this

[image]

All is fine when Viewing this on a mobile and desktop, but when I minimize the browser to a ipad screen it renders like this

[image]

Ideally I would like it to stack, so the first row would be

- First row = Panel +
- Second row = Panel =
- Third row = Panel

Probably an easy fix for a bootstrap master I'm sure.

Comment: I removed my thoroughly unhelpful answer. Sorry I couldn't help. Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it to work, after playing around with .col in firebug the end result I applied

```
col-md-12 col-md-1
```

to the plus and equals image and it now displays as expected.